# PushWoosh notificationCallback not firing

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, push-notification, pushwoosh

here is my code. When my app is killed it and restarted on a push notification it should redirect properly however it never actually goes into the     `pushNotification.notificationCallback = function(event)` Have no clue as to why.

```
function initPushWoosh() {
                try {
                    checkNetworkConnection();

                    if(!window.plugins) {
                        wodifyRedirect('unknown-' + device.token);
                        return;
                    }

                    var pushNotification = window.plugins.pushNotification;
                    pushNotification.notificationCallback = function(event) {
                        var notificationId = 0;
                        if(event.u && event.u.custom) {
                            notificationId = event.u.custom;
                        } else if(event.u) {
                            notificationId = JSON.parse(event.u).custom;
                        } else if(event.custom && event.custom.custom) {
                            notificationId = event.custom.custom;
                        } else if(event.custom) { 
                            notificationId = JSON.parse(event.custom).custom;
                        }

                        if(event.onStart && notificationId != 0) {
                            navigateToNotifications(notificationId, device.uuid);
                        }
                    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually Pushwoosh defines its own notification callback:

```
PushNotification.prototype.notificationCallback = function(notification) {
            var ev = document.createEvent('HTMLEvents');
            ev.notification = notification;
            ev.initEvent('push-notification', true, true, arguments);
            document.dispatchEvent(ev);
    };
```

this could be handled by:

```
document.addEventListener('push-notification', function(event) {
```

See Pushwoosh sample app here:

https://github.com/shaders/phonegap-3-sample-app/tree/master/www